# How to remove blur from svg line

Tags: svg, line

I have two line Line one is not smooth (blur). While line is smooth. How can I render it smooth.

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="10" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: The lines are drawn anti-aliased to make them look smoother.  But there is only so much that can be done given the size of the pixels.  Especially with very shallow angles like that.  Take a screen shot and magnify it and you will see that it's doing the best that it can.  What you see is the best you are going to get.  You are going to have to live with it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your distinction between smooth and blur but you can use shape-rendering="crispEdges" to get rid of anti-aliasing on shapes.

```html
<svg height="210" width="500" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="10" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: the line close to top is still ziczac, while other is not

Comment: Screens are made of rectangular pixels of non-zero dimension. Anti-aliasing is a technique used to give the appearance of smooth lines using semi-opaque "filler" pixels. There is no Santa Claus:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing